# Can't read custom UIKit events

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, getuikit

UIKit has several custom events that are fired.  For example, when switching tabs, a `change.uk.tab` event is fired (https://getuikit.com/docs/tab.html).  The problem is I can only read the event if I prefix JQuery's `"$"` with `UIKit.$`.  It's as if UIKit's jQuery `$` is returning a different object.

So for example, this will work:

```
UIkit.$('#tabs').on('change.uk.tab', function(e, active, previous) {
    console.log("uk tab changed: " + active.context.id);
});
```

Here's the html:

```
<ul id="tabs" class="uk-tab" data-uk-tab >
    <li id="tabPage1" class="uk-active"><a href="">tabPage1</a></li>
    <li id="tabPage2"><a href="">tabPage2</a></li>
    <li id="tabPage3"><a href="">tabPage3</a></li>
</ul>
```

However, if I were to remove the `"UIkit."` and just use the `"$"` object alone:

```
$('#tabs').on('change.uk.tab', function(e, active, previous) {
    console.log("uk tab changed: " + active.context.id);
});
```

then I wouldn't see the `change.uk.tab` event.  (That is, the `console.log` line is never executed.)  Why is this?  What's the difference between `"UiKit.$"` and just `"$"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in:

> [doc](https://getuikit.com/docs/documentation_javascript.html):
>
> `<!-- Element within a modal, switcher or dropdown -->
>
> <div id="myelement" data-uk-check-display>...</div>
>
> <script>
>
> $("#myelement").on('display.uk.check', function(){
>         // custom code to adjust height etc on show
>      });
>   </script>`

you can avoid UIkit.$('#tabs') and use directly $('#tabs').

You can see in you console UIkit is an object containing a reference to $ or better jQuery.

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  console.log('UIkit.$.fn.jquery: ' + UIkit.$.fn.jquery);
  console.log('$.fn.jquery: ' + $.fn.jquery);
  $('#tabs').on('change.uk.tab', function(e, active, previous) {
    console.log("uk tab changed: " + active.context.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.1/css/uikit.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.1/js/uikit.min.js"></script>


<ul id="tabs" class="uk-tab" data-uk-tab >
    <li id="tabPage1" class="uk-active"><a href="">tabPage1</a></li>
    <li id="tabPage2"><a href="">tabPage2</a></li>
    <li id="tabPage3"><a href="">tabPage3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah, so this does work.  I see my error.  I imported jquery twice in my html, using "<script src=".  (once after uikit.min.js was imported. )